# Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table on reindexing product flat data

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, database

I am new to magento. I am stuck on reindexing issue in magento. When I go to Index management. I see this screen

[image]

When I run reindex data from command line "**php indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_flat**" I got error message as

```
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-7607_9061'' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(420): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(341): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2570): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(7)
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

Please help me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! On a production environment. How did you manage to solve ir?

Comment: Actually... problem was that on server I have max-connection for sql was low and thats why it was time out and some temp table having this issue. I found slow query log and optimize it.

Comment: Nothing in my slow query log :(

Comment: That was one scenario.. Which was in my case...